# How to execute commands on an EC2 instance using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Can anyone tell me if I can execute shell commands using `boto3` on an AWS instance?

I read about `boto.manage.cmdshell` in a few places, but it is deprecated in `boto3`.

Answer (score 27):

```
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
response = ssm_client.send_command(
            InstanceIds=['i-03#####'],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            Parameters={'commands': ['start ecs']}, )

command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
      CommandId=command_id,
      InstanceId='i-03######',
    )
print(output)
```

Comment: Please provide some context so the reader can understand the code rather than copy+paste

Answer (score 9):

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm' )    
testCommand = ssm.send_command( InstanceIds=[ 'i-123123123123' ], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', Comment='la la la', OutputS3BucketName='myOutputS3Bucket', OutputS3KeyPrefix='i-123123123123', Parameters={ "commands":[ "ip config" ]  } )
```

i-123123123123 is a pretend ec2 instance id. 
I put that in the OutputS3KeyPrefix to get a unique place to store logs in the bucket.

You can install the ssm agent like this;

```
ec2r = boto3.resource('ec2' )
userdata = """#cloud-config
    runcmd:
     - /home/ec2-user/sudo npm run prod
     - cd /tmp
     - curl https://amazon-ssm-%s.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm -o amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
     - yum install -y amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
""" % region   

if ssm == "on":
    instance = ec2r.create_instances( ImageId=ami, MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, KeyName=keyname, InstanceType=instancetype, 
        NetworkInterfaces=[{
        'DeviceIndex': 0,
        'AssociatePublicIpAddress': False,
        'SubnetId': mySub,
        'Groups': secGroupList,
        'AssociatePublicIpAddress': AssociatePublicIpAddress
    }],
        Monitoring={ 'Enabled': False },

        UserData=userdata,
        IamInstanceProfile={
            'Name': rolename
        },
        EbsOptimized=False
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution. As someone with experience here, would you advocate using paramiko over SSM given its simplicity? The devs in the github issue here:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/328
seem to prefer it over SSM for executing shell scripts.

Comment: I've gotten into cloudformation templates for doing deploys. It helps to make it clear what you have already deployed in the cf console.

Answer (score 8):

I know I am answering to bit old thread. I am not sure even at that time SSM existed. But now you can use SSM send_command from boto3 to run commands directly on ec2 instances.
Here is the sample to run PowerShell commands on EC2 instances

```
import boto3
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name="us-west-2") # use region code in which you are working
response = ssm_client.send_command(
             InstanceIds=[
                "i-03########" # use instance id on which you want to execute, even multiple is allowd
                     ],
             DocumentName="AWS-RunPowerShellScript",
             Parameters={
                'commands':[
                     'ipconfig'
                       ]
                   },
             })
command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
      CommandId=command_id,
      InstanceId='i-03######',
    )
print(output)
```

For more information read [boto3 SSM docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command)
For information on SSM itself refer AWS docs

Comment: what should i do for creating user name and password using AWS-RunPowerShellScript? Can any one help me to do?

Answer (score 2):

No. The [`boto.manage.cmdshell`](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/manage/cmdshell.py) functionality in boto was not migrated to boto3. The original `boto.manage.cmdshell` functionality used [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) which you could use directly with boto3 if you want to have SSH functionality with boto3.

Here's a [boto3 github issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/333) on this topic.

As @jarmod points out there is [new AWS functionality](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/) as of October 2015 that enables you to run commands on Windows systems using [AWS EC2 SSM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ssm/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). You can access this in boto3 with the [boto3 SSM client](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ssm.html) as of botocore version 1.3.1.

Here's a [boto3 github issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/328) on supporting "EC2 Run Command"

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am going to try Paramiko.

Comment: Also take a look at the recently-announced EC2 Run Command: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/. The blog suggests that it's supported in boto3 and the awscli, though I have yet to find it. Here's the FAQ: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/faqs/

Comment: @Gil Can you add more detail, what isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
```

to

```
command_id = context.aws_request_id
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html) says:

> aws_request_id
>
> AWS request ID associated with the request. This is the ID returned to the client that called the invoke method.

Change:

```
command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
```

for:

```
command_id = context.aws_request_id
```

Comment: Why post the same answer twice?