# How to pass commands to ec2 after starting an instance from python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to run a python script that can start an instance and then run some commands. I know it can be passed if I try to create an instance in the form of userdata. What I am trying to figure out is how to pass it if I am starting an already created instance. Following is the code using boto3 to pass simple hello world while creating an instance:

```
import boto3
userdata = """#cloud-config

repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all

packages:
 - s3cmd

runcmd:
 - echo 'Hello S3!' > /tmp/hello.txt
 - aws --region YOUR_REGION s3 cp /tmp/hello.txt s3://YOUR_BUCKET/hello.txt
"""

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-f5f41398',         # default Amazon linux
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    KeyName='YOUR_SSH_KEY_NAME',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    IamInstanceProfile={
        'Arn': 'YOUR_ARN_ID'
    },
    SecurityGroupIds=['YOUR_SECURITY_GROUP_NAME'],
    UserData=userdata
)
```

Something like

```
i = ec2.Instance(id='i-5fea4d42')
i.start('pass commands here: eg echo xx, mv a b/ etc')
```

Comment: You want to run different command every time or the same command you have in user-data?

Comment: I am trying to execute commands on the ec2 shel. They will be different, I am trying to use boto and command shell, which was not carried over to boto3 link. Probably I will use a combination of paramiko and boto3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use paramiko along with boto3 and awscli to run everything on cloud in an automated way.

```
import paramiko
import boto3
import time
import subprocess
import awscli
import os

# Starting instance, copying data to instance, running model, copying output to s3
print ("\nCreating ssh session")
session = boto3.Session()
ec2 = session.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
i = ec2.Instance(id='instance id') # instance id


print('\nstarting deeplearning_ami instance')
i.start()
i.wait_until_running()
i.load()
print ("Waiting for the checks to finish..")
time.sleep(45)

k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(key_path) #your private key for ssh
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ("\nConnecting to shell using ssh")
c.connect( hostname = i.public_dns_name, username = "ec2-user", pkey = k )

print ("\nExecuting commands on EC2 instance\n")

stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(""" mkdir -p model;
                                        printf 'Creating directory structure, if it does not exists \n';
                                        cd model;
                                        mkdir -p data out cp;
                                        printf '\nCopying code from s3 bucket to ec2 instance \n';
                                        aws s3 cp {0} .;
                                        printf '\nDownloading data from s3 bucket to ec2 instance';
                                        aws s3 sync {1} data;
                                        printf '\n Download complete, running model..\n\n';
                                        python theano_test.py;
                                        echo 'Hello S3!' > out/hello.txt;
                                        printf '\n Copying output to s3 bucket \n';
                                        aws s3 sync out {2} """.format(s3_code,s3_data,s3_out), get_pty=True)

for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(2048), ""): print(line, end="")
print ("\n \n Processingfinished")

#print ('Stopping instance')
i.stop() 


print ('Copying output from s3 bucket to local')
os.system('aws s3 sync ' + s3_out + ' ' + local_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UserData and start the instance and it will pick up the change:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_instance_attribute

However, UserData scripts are usually only set to run once, so you will have to modify it to run on every boot:
[How do I make cloud-init startup scripts run every time my EC2 instance boots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475374/how-do-i-make-cloud-init-startup-scripts-run-every-time-my-ec2-instance-boots)

Another way would be to set up SSH and run a script after boot, but shoving this in UserData is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I am trying to use boto and command shell, which was not carried over to boto3 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028219/how-to-execute-commands-on-aws-instance-using-boto3). Probably I will use a combination of paramiko and boto3.