# Run a batch file on EC2 from a (python) lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I can see a generic way of starting an EC2 from lambda in [Start and Stop Instances at Scheduled Intervals Using Lambda and CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/).

Suppose I use that method to start an EC2, and suppose the AMI is a windows server 2019 customised to have a `.bat` file on the desktop, and also suppose I'm using a python lambda.

How can I execute this batch file from the lambda? (i.e. just as though someone had RDP'd into the instance and double-clicked on it)

Note: To be very clear, basically I want to start the EC2 using the method given in the AWS docs (above), and right after the instance has started, to run the batch file that will be sitting on the instance's desktop

Comment: You are looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028219/how-to-execute-commands-on-aws-instance-using-boto3 -- also check boto3 for ssm https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html -- choose AWS-RunShellScript for linux and AWS-RunPowerShellScript for windows instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few concepts mixed together.

AWS Lambda functions run on the Lambda service, **without having to use Amazon EC2 instances**. This is what makes them "serverless".

If you have a batch file on an Amazon EC2 instance, you would presumably want to **run that batch file on the EC2 instance itself**, without involving Lambda (since you *have* got a server).

If you wish to run a script on an EC2 instance when it launches for the first time, you can **provide a PowerShell or Command-Line script via the User Data field**. Software on the AMI will automatically execute this script the first time that the instance starts.

This script could do all the work itself, or it could simply call another script that is stored on the disk. Some people use the script to download another script from a repository (eg Amazon S3 or GitHub) and then execute the downloaded script.

For more information, see: [Running Commands on Your Windows Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

If the Amazon EC2 instance is **already running and you wish to trigger a script** to execute, you can use the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). This works by having an agent on the instance which can be remotely triggered, thereby running scripts without having to login to the instance.

Comment: Thanks John. In case there is a better way, what I want to do is make an EC2 start and run a script then shut down every 24 hours. The script could take between 5 min to 5 hours (also, the script is not written in a lambda supported language), so I figure EC2 is the best tool for the job? I have assumed lambda is the best way to make the EC2 start and execute the script. But perhaps I should be using something else? Very interested in your thoughts

Comment: While Amazon CloudWatch Events has a scheduling function, it cannot start/launch an Amazon EC2 instance. It can, however, trigger a Lambda function that can do this. I would recommend using Lambda to launch a _NEW_ instance that uses a User Data script to trigger the job. When the job is finished, it can terminate its own EC2 instance. (The alternative is start/stop, but then you will need another way to trigger the job on the instance.)