# Execution of commands on an AWS Windows EC2 instance using pywinrm fails because WSMan AllowUnencrypted is set to False

Tags: python-3.x, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, winrm

I am trying to connect to a Windows EC2 instance and run some commands against it using `pywinrm`.
I am using the following code to create a session:
`session = winrm.Session(ec2_instance.public_dns_name, auth=(user_name, password))`
which works fine.

Now, when I use the session object created above to run a command like:
`session.run_ps("hostname")` or `session.run_cmd("hostname")` -> it fails with a timeout error because the firewall rules for WinRM ports `5985` and `5986` are not configured (The security group on AWS side has the ports open but the VM does not have it).

Once the inbound rule for ports `5985` and `5986` is configured on the EC2 instance, running any command fails with the following error:
`Exception has occurred: InvalidCredentialsError the specified credentials were rejected by the server`

I know that error message is misleading because the credentials are correct.
The reason I say that the credentials are correct because when I run the following from the EC2 instance:

```
Set-Item -Force WSMan:\localhost\Service\auth\Basic $true
Set-Item -Force WSMan:\localhost\Service\AllowUnencrypted $true
```

And then run the command using my code, it all works fine.

Now, what I am trying to find is, a way to enable the `AllowUnencrypted` value through my python code.
I have looked at using `Kerberos` but it seems like I need to create an [AWS Managed Microsoft AD directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_getting_started_create_directory.html) which will incur cost to my organization.

I have also tried to use `NTLM` like this:

```
protocol = Protocol(
            endpoint=f"https://{ec2_instance.public_dns_name}:5985/wsman",
            transport="ntlm",
            username="Administrator",
            password="Password",
            server_cert_validation="ignore",
        )

shell_id = protocol.open_shell()
```

But I get the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)')))"

From your error, port 5985 is HTTP listener where as HTTPS should be port 5986.

Change endpoint port to 5986 and give a try "endpoint=f"https://{ec2_instance.public_dns_name}:5986/wsman","

Sorry I'm unable to add comment yet.

Comment: Thanks Adaikal.
I tried your suggestion but it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

Step 1:
Use AWS SSM to run commands on an EC2 instance. These commands will

- Set `WMan` attributes `Basic Authentication` to `True` and `AllowUnencrypted` to `True`.
- Create Windows Firewall Rules with ports `5985` and `5986`.

```
Set-Item -Force WSMan:\localhost\Service\auth\Basic $true
Set-Item -Force WSMan:\localhost\Service\AllowUnencrypted $true
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow WinRM Ports" -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 5985-5986
```

I got help from here: [How to execute commands on AWS Instance using Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028219/how-to-execute-commands-on-aws-instance-using-boto3)

AMIs with SSM pre-installed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-win.html

> Note: The commands can only be run on an EC2 instance if it has this IAM profile associated to it:
> ARN = `arn:aws:iam::<your_aws_account_id>:instance-profile/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup`
> Name = `AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup`
> This can be done using boto3 EC2 `client` method `associate_iam_instance_profile()`

> Once the IAM is associated to the EC2 instance, it takes a minute or two to take this effect and get listed under `describe_instance_information()` method of boto3 `ssm` client.
> Make sure to add a waiting method for your EC2 instance to be listed under the output of the above method before trying to run any command.

Step 2:
Use `WinRM` python library to bring EBS disk online, initialize, partition and format the disk.

> Note: I could have used SSM to run the commands mentioned above but `WinRM` provides better output which can be converted to JSON and used for further validation.

Step 3:
Code to decrypt password for login:

```
from winrm.protocol import Protocol
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5

with open(private_key_file_path, "r") as key_file:
     key_text = key_file.read()
        

     key = RSA.importKey(key_text)
     cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
     password = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(password_data),None).decode("utf-8")
```